# CUSTOMDRAW in Win32 Header not appropriately drawing outside columns area

Tags: c++, winapi, controls

I am currently subclassing a ListView control to support custom color schemes - especially Dark Mode themes.

So first, I changed the ListView and associated Header with:

```
SetWindowTheme(hwndListView, isDarkModeEnabled() ? L"Explorer" : nullptr, nullptr);
SetWindowTheme(hwndListViewHeader, isDarkModeEnabled() ? L"ItemsView" : nullptr, nullptr);
```

I can set the ListView background color to any custom color I choose, while answering to the `WM_THEMECHANGED` message and doing a `ListView_SetBkColor()` macro.

Unfortunately, it seems I can't do it with the associated Header Control, I must resort to Custom Draw. So I did. I subclassed the ListView, because this is the window handle that will receive `WM_NOTIFY` messages from the Header control, and when responding to `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` message, my code looks like this:

```
        case WM_NOTIFY:
        {
            LPNMHDR nmhdr = reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam);
            if (nmhdr->code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
            {
                LPNMCUSTOMDRAW lpcd = reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lParam);
                switch (lpcd->dwDrawStage)
                {
                case CDDS_PREPAINT:
                {
                    if (!PluginDarkMode::isEnabled())
                        return CDRF_DODEFAULT;

                    FillRect(lpcd->hdc, &lpcd->rc, getDarkerBackgroundBrush());
                    return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW | CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT;
                }
                case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
                {

                    return DrawListViewHeaderItem(lParam); // This function draws the item entirely and then returns CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT.
                }

                case CDDS_POSTPAINT:

                    // Calculates the undrawn border outside columns
                    HWND hHeader = lpcd->hdr.hwndFrom;
                    int count = static_cast<int>(Header_GetItemCount(hHeader));
                    int colsWidth = 0;
                    RECT wRc = {};
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        Header_GetItemRect(hHeader, i, &wRc);
                        colsWidth += wRc.right - wRc.left;
                    }

                    RECT clientRect;
                    GetClientRect(hHeader, &clientRect);
                    if (clientRect.right > (colsWidth + 1))
                    {
                        clientRect.left = colsWidth + 1;
                        HDC hdc = GetDC(hHeader);
                        FillRect(hdc, &clientRect, getDarkerBackgroundBrush());
                        ReleaseDC(hHeader, hdc);
                    }

                    return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT;
                }
            }

            break;
        }
```

Now, my **problem** is that, although this seems fine, my control will always end up with a **black rectangle** outside the column's area (the empty space where no column exists). And this effect persists up until I move the mouse outside the header control area.

For example:

[image: Picture of control with bug]

And when the mouse leaves the area:

[image: Picture of control after mouse leave the painting header]

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: I actually solved it by drawing the entire Header myself (responding to `WM_PAINT`) instead of using CustomDraw. But if someone can provide a better answer, I'm still open, because on WM_PAINT I get more flickering than normal and I guess it is slower than drawing only the required items.

Comment: The blank area isn't something the control expects you to draw via custom draw - there's no way to stop it doing its own drawing. But what you can do is to draw it yourself when you get the CDDS_PREPAINT notification, and clip out the blank area from the HDC you're given using ExcludeClipRect. That stops the control drawing over it with the default color. Note that the rectangle you're given in CDDS_PREPAINT is the current area marked for repainting, not the full control - you can get that with GetClientRect.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter, that worked. I calculated the undrawn area and then ExcludeClipRect. This is one step to avoid owner-drawing the entire control. Now, no matter what I tried, I could not intercept a CDDS_ITEMPOSTERASE for a header. If I could do that, that would also enable me to not resort to draw the entire item on CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT (and return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT). Do you also know of any method, if all to intercept that message (CDDS_ITEMPOSTERASE)? It seems Header controls don't even send them, am I right? Thanks in advance anyway.

Comment: I don't think so, if it doesn't send it, it doesn't send it. Not all controls implement the full custom drawing API.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I just realized that the background color is somewhat "hardcoded" into the item part called HEADERITEM inside aero.msstyles. Microsoft made images for them instead of just defining rectangle colors. So I guess if I want to really customize my items background I'll have to keep drawing at least the items fully by myself. Anyway, I'll leave this comment here for anyone after me to realize there is no way to easily draw the header items backgrounds. Thanks anyway. Bye.